# Reading PHP_INT_MAX or near value by (f|v|s)scanf functions

Tags: php, linux, 64-bit, integer, scanf

I am running 64-bit Ubuntu Linux. [php](/questions/tagged/php) is also 64-bit.  I am trying to read integer from a file using fscanf. It seems fscanf can not scan integer of more than 32 bit. See the demonstration bellow.

```
var_dump(
    $a = PHP_INT_MAX, 
    --$a, 
    (string)$a, 
    sscanf((string)$a, "%u"), 
    PHP_INT_SIZE
);
```

Output

```
int(9223372036854775807)
int(9223372036854775806)
string(19) "9223372036854775806"
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "4294967294"
}
int(8)
```

See, the 64-bit integer arithmetic works! It just the sscanf function thats not working. May be I am missing a *proper format*.
How can i read 64-bit integers in PHP using scanf? What will be the format?

Comment: PHP version? [Bug #47842 sscanf() does not support 64-bit values](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47842)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that you need to upgrade your PHP version to a more modern version.  It appears that [5.2 has this issue](http://codepad.viper-7.com/rGxBtl), but it's fixed in [5.3](http://codepad.viper-7.com/bVQL0I)

So upgrade your PHP version, and you should be good to go...  (and that's not counting that 5.2 is EOL for a while now)...

Comment: I am using [**PHP 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.14**](http://pastie.org/3577267). Why is showing such errors?

Comment: Upgrade from 5.3.2 to the latest version of 5.3...  It was fixed nearly 2 years ago.  From looking at dates, 5.3.3 should have the fix...